# How can I combine cells in a row in a latex-table?

Tags: latex, tex

In a table I want to combine some of the columns, but not in all rows. How can I realize this with LaTeX?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`\multicolumn{<number>}{<formatting>}{<contents>}`

Where the arguments are

1. Number of columns to merge
2. the justification and formating string (just like you use in the table header, i.e. "`|c|`" or the like)
3. The contents to put in the merged columns

This command simply replaces the `<number>` columns and is used inline.

---

**Addition:** This is also how you change the formatting of a single field in only one row of the table. Just use `\multicolumn{1}{<new format>}{<contents>}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. My first problem was, that I set as formatting only {c} and at this rows no lines were drawn. I had to change format-param to {|c|}, that worked as expected.

Comment: You have to add \\ at the end of the line as with any other line.

Comment: Nice solution!!