# How can I restrict the size of my \multicolumn cells in a longtable?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, longtable

I have a really long table in LaTeX that spans several pages and is (as it is now) also too wide for the page.

I am using the longtable package with every column width specified with the `p{width}` command.

The problem is, that most of the rows contain a multicolumn call, and thus are not adhering to the preamble `p{width}` command, which causes the total width of the table to be too large.

Minimal example:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{1in}|p{0.75in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|>{p{1in}|p{1in}|}
\caption{some cap} \label{somelable}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Text Header One}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Text Header Two}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Three}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Four}} \tabularnewline \cline{1-4}
\textbf{Five} & \textbf{Six} & \textbf{Seven} & \textbf{Eight} &  & \tabularnewline \hline
Some Text String & Longer Text String Here & More Text Here & Text Example & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hlineExample Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Multi-column Text String that doesn't fit column width} & Text & Text \tabularnewline \hline
Example Text String Two & Longer Text String Example Two & width of box & text & Text & Text  \tabularnewline \hline
\end{longtable}
```

I am loading longtable in my preamble, and running pdflatex several times (as outlined in the longtable documentation). It compiles with 0 warnings and 0 errors.

How can I get normal "narrow" cells?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using `|p{<sum of widths>}|` for the formatting option to `\multicolumn`?

Just guessing here.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: @IRus The second argument to `\multicolumn` is a format specifier that takes the same meaning as in the second argument to a `tabular` environment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440228/how-can-i-combine-cells-in-a-row-in-a-latex-table for a summary of how to use it. Mica's situation here is an interesting corner case where he was relying on fixed column widths and the multicolumn opening things up too much.

Comment: Sum of widths is not enough, especially if you have a lot of columns merged. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204911/how-to-specify-the-multicolumn-width-in-table-header

Answer (score 4):

You have to give a size parameter to multicolumns even though there is a preamble size. The next example is a multicolumn cell of the size of the table width:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth} p{0.7\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{ p{\textwidth}} {YOUR TEXT HERE}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

\begin{longtable}{p{2.8cm} p{2.8cm} worked for me..