# How to align the long caption of the table in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I have a longtable in LaTeX with a caption that doesn't fit into one line, e.g.

```
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
\caption{This is a very long caption that does not fit into one line}
...
\end{longtable}
```

The resulting PDF looks as follows:

```
Figure 1: This is a very long caption that does not fit
into one line
```

I would like the second line of the caption be either aligned with the start of the caption (not the text "Figure 1") to make it look like

```
Figure 1: This is a very long caption that does not fit
          into one line
```

or at least make the caption text be centered.
How can I do this?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110961/latex-longtable-package-pwidth-and-multicolumn-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What documentclass are you using?

If you use something from komascript, your wish should be the default.

So I suppose, you do not use komascript. Then, try the [`caption`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=caption) package. You have to specify the option `format=hang` in order to get what you want (i.e. `\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}`.